# Too much noise while recording sound from mic on 14.04 LTS

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone, audio-recording

I want to record sound from mic in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I do this with good quality in windows 7 or 8.1. I am using the pulse input(pulse audio) with audacity. It records voices but with lots of noises. I use noise removal in effect tab but the outcome has very bad quality.

I tried audio recorder but it record voices with noise, too.

Can anyone help me?

My laptop is a Lenovo z410.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Type in the terminal `alsamixer`. It will open the present levels, adjust the microphone level at 75 and set the microphone boss level to 50. Worked for me perfectly and removed the noise from microphone.

Comment: i don't understand your answer completely but it guide me to another way. after entering alsamixer, i press f4 to enter capture tab. then i set capture to 28 and internal mic boost to 51. the recording quality change a lot and it's now acceptable.

Comment: I used mic boost 53 and capture 70 and it works great, no random noise!

Comment: I've dropped the internal mic boost to 0 or 22, the results are perfect!

![alt text](https://i.imgur.com/VbreGPZl.png "alsamixer internal + headset setup")

Comment: impossible! I already wanted to buy another mic or audiocard

Comment: Sorry for excavating, but this still works in 2023.   I had to use 
```
alsamixer -D pulse
``` 
to get to the pulse audio controls, and then select my card (F6).   That brought me to a whole lot more settings where I could control the gain for the front and back microphones independently.  Set the gain for everything to 0, and viola! no noise.

Answer (score 13):

I tried this method it didn't work for me. I tried to active noise cancelation and it works perfectly. Here it is:

I found this solution [Video](https://youtu.be/gKsBAEnVxEA) , and it worked for me.

Open Terminal and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Add these lines at the end of the file:

```
### Enable Echo/Noise-Cancelation
load-module module-echo-cancel aec_method=webrtc aec_args="analog_gain_control=0 digital_gain_control=1" source_name=echoCancel_source sink_name=echoCancel_sink
set-default-source echoCancel_source
set-default-sink echoCancel_sink
```

exit from text editor with ctrl+x and save file.

run

```
 pulseaudio -k
 pulseaudio --start
```

restart the system.

Done!

From:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1222714/864419

Comment: In my case this improved the situation, but it makes the audio quality worse (digital distortion) & the hiss is still present, even if it's attenuated  :/ 
Thanks anyway, I think that this is the right track to follow

Answer (score 6):

I will provide a full answer based on answers given here and elsewhere.

So my recording was a total mess: sounds crackling, popping, with the sound of the processor, or the fan of the laptop.

What I did was to input the following commands:

1/ Restore alsactl

```
alsactl restore
```

It improved tremendously the quality but was still bad.

2/ Adjust microphone with Alsa mixer (Rajashekhar Ch's answer)

```
alsamixer
```

then

```
Fn + F4
Right arrow
Bring capture to !30 and microboost to ~50 
ESC
```

3/ Followed Mohammad's answer:
edit /etc/pulse/default.pa by adding at the end:

```
### Enable Echo/Noise-Cancelation
load-module module-echo-cancel aec_method=webrtc aec_args="analog_gain_control=0 digital_gain_control=1" source_name=echoCancel_source sink_name=echoCancel_sink
set-default-source echoCancel_source
set-default-sink echoCancel_sink
```

Then

```
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

4/ Activate Noise cancellation in OBS:

[image]

You have to click on the settings button and then filters as seen on screenshot.

[image]

Play with the different ranges to see what works best for you.

Comment: this does not work for me ,their was still a lot of noise

Comment: actual worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Tried all of the above,None of the above answer worked for me.ONLY thing I am doing now is recording audio with mobile (100% clear sound) adding them with video editor. Double work but better result than creepy air/laptop fan sound from internal mic.

Answer (score 0):

While recording, click at top right where you control sound. In the mic bar present there, just reduce the sensitivity of mic. This will remove the creepy sound of air and you can enjoy your sound

Answer (score 0):

This is often happening to me while using Linux in ubuntu.
Here is my solution and it is work for me

- First, check your external device.if everything working fine, Move ahead.
- Type command in a terminal, `sudo alsa force-reload` and after reboot your pc.If still not working follow the next step.
- `sudo apt remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio`

`sudo apt install alsa-base pulseaudio` Type this command in terminal and reboot your pc.

Hope this will helpful for you

Answer (score -1):

I clean the files afterwards by using `sox`. See this article, called “[The Sox of Silence](https://digitalcardboard.com/blog/2009/08/25/the-sox-of-silence/)”.