# Ubuntu 18.04 Microphone crackling / popping sound

Tags: microphone, noise

I’m using Ubuntu 18.04 installed on a laptop (Toshiba Satellite L675D-S7052) with an internal microphone. When I use the terminal to record a sound `sox -t alsa default ./recording.wav`, or use discord, I can hear a loud crackling / popping noise during playback. I’ve tried the many options (noise / echo canceling) by editing the `etc/pulse/default.pa` file with no success.

I’ve also tried lowering the microphone input volume under “settings”, but regardless the input level bar still jumps randomly in a very quiet room.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Audio and video files play without any distortion. The microphone worked fine with Windows 10. I've also tried an external microphone that yielded the same results.

[Microphone settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5eSl.png)

Comment: does a similar issue happen when you record using other packages? do voice/video chats work?

Comment: yes, the issue seems to be system-wide irregardless of the application that's used during the recording process. (thanks for your comment :) )

Comment: no problem! do you have the necessary drivers for your microphone? (might be redundant to ask, but i'm just going through the obvious). i'll be looking to see if there are any drivers that Ubuntu needs for a Toshiba laptop.

Comment: I've checked the "additional drivers" tab under "software & updates". It states that no additional drivers are available. `alsamixer` states the following: 
**Card: HDA ATI SB**                              
**Chip: Realtek ALC259**

Comment: according to the Toshiba website, no drivers exist for the microphone under Linux devices. i'm not 100% certain, but i feel like that might be partially the reason why. can you possibly find a second, separate microphone to check whether it's *all* or just the built-in?

Comment: I have used an external microphone (standard audio jack input);  However, the results are the same. I guess I should buy USB headset and give that a try. Nevertheless thank you for your help!

Comment: if it doesn't work with a USB headset either, check back here and let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution [Video](https://youtu.be/gKsBAEnVxEA) , and it worked for me.

Open Terminal and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Add these lines at the end of the file:

```
### Enable Echo/Noise-Cancelation
load-module module-echo-cancel aec_method=webrtc aec_args="analog_gain_control=0 digital_gain_control=1" source_name=echoCancel_source sink_name=echoCancel_sink
set-default-source echoCancel_source
set-default-sink echoCancel_sink
```

exit from text editor with ctrl+x and save file.

run

```
 pulseaudio -k
 pulseaudio --start
```

restart the system.

Done!

Comment: this helped me on ubuntu 20.04 on Lenovo Y540. thanks!